# .begin_search not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, webpack

I have typescript function. Here is code

```
 export class Step1{
  constructor(){
    this.begin_search();
    this.results_ready();

  }

  private begin_search():void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      Searchfield.show_searchfield()
    }, 100);

    $('.search_box_overlay').show()
    $('.search_box_overlay_top').show()
    if (gon.search['search_type'] == 'package')
      $('.search_box_overlay_top .package').show()
    else if (gon.search['search_type'] == 'hotel')
      $('.search_box_overlay_top .hotel').show()
    else
      $('.search_box_overlay_top .air').show()

    window.seach_status_task = setInterval(Itinerary.check_search_status, 2000)
    window.search_loading_itineraries = false
  }
```

And then I importing this code into pack

Like this

```
 $(document).ready(() => {
  Translation.addDict(gon.translations);
  Track.initialize();

  new Searchfield();
  if (!gon.search['searched']) {
    Step1.begin_search();


  }
  if (gon && gon.search['id'] && $('.offer_hotel_addon').length > 0) {
    check_status();
  }
});
```

But when I run project, I have this error.

> **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__components_step1**.a.begin_search is not a function

Where can be problem and how I need to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The code defines `begin_search` as an instance method (a part of an instance), but is trying to use them as if they were `static` (a part of the class itself). Mark the method as `static` so that it belongs to the `Step1` class itself:

```
private static begin_search():void {
```

[See the handbook for more info on static methods.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#static-properties) I'd also remove the `this.begin_search();` call from the constructor as well. When the method is static, it doesn't exist on `this` anymore.

Comment: Yeah. But as I understood than in constructor, I can't use `this.begin_search()`?

Comment: And I need to use it like `Step1.begin_search?`

Comment: Exactly, and you shouldn't need to use it in the constructor, since it doesn't look like you're making instances of the class anyway. I might even suggest making `begin_search()` into a normal standalone function. No reason to have a class if you're not using it as a class is meant to be used 

Comment: Okay. Will try. Thank's

Comment: Okay, seems it helps. But about standalone functions. Can you make example?

Comment: You talk about making functions and just importing them?